# Will Stack Overflow consider supporting third-party highlight.js packages?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

One of the nice features of [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) is its [plugin framework](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/extra/3RD_PARTY_QUICK_START.md) which adds support for third-party programming languages that are not supported by the main highlight.js development team.

With Stack Overflow's switch from Google Prettify to `highlight.js`, are there any plans to make use of this feature to enable highlighting of additional languages beyond the core set?

Comment: The trouble is you'd pay for the download of all of this for every question even though in 99.999% of cases it wouldn't be used.

Comment: @RobertLongson Most of JavaScript for Stack Exchange is lazy-loaded. It would be reasonable and expect that the needed plugins would A) only need to be added to the page on pages where they were needed (e.g. pages explicitly needing specific languages; or pages with code not covered in the default set); or B) that the grammars would be cached by the browser, so unlikely to actually cost bandwidth for every page. It would also be possible for SE to run the full set against new versions of a post and record which grammars are needed specifically for that post, or any of many other optimizations.

Comment: However, that doesn't cover the issue of allowing users to specify random 3rd party plugins. Allowing that to happen is, actually, allowing users to specify arbitrary JavaScript to be run on the pages on which they have a question or answer. That's a *huge* security issue, which would lead to major problems.

Comment: @Makyen — w.r.t. the very reasonable security concern you raise, is there anything about the highlight.js build/test/release process that would (or could) validate that a given version of a third-party highlight package is benign (or at least, no less benign than highlight.js itself?).  I'm thinking of the typical definition file being a list of key-value properties like keywords, regex matches, etc. without directly specifying any executable code itself, merely leveraging that which is already baked into highlight.js.

Comment: @Brad I'm not familiar enough with highlight.js to be able to say. Presumably, highlight.js is all open source and can be reviewed who desires to do so. SE has chosen to include it with their pages. While I'm certainly concerned about security on my machine, the things which JavaScript included with the page can do are primarily limited by the browser to (mostly) affecting the domain from which the page originates.So, yes, it's possible for something which SE has chosen to include to carry nefarious code, but SE's choice to include it makes it primarily their responsibility to review the code.

Comment: [Highlight.js maintainer here] "random" 3rd party plugins might indeed be a real problem, but SE could curate a list of "approved" grammars if they so chose. Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending who you ask) language grammars are literally  executable Javascript code - so out of the box they can do anything JavaScript can do... it would be pretty easy to "audit" a grammar at a glance though - 95% of most grammars is static definition.  ...or to manually "flatten" a grammar down to just raw data - although some grammars may lose features or break then.

Comment: [Re: flattening] This is actually how the PHP port of Highlight.js works... it "executes" the grammars with JS (at built time) and then takes the resulting data structure and just persists that (so that their PHP runtime can use it as data). This becomes harder though as languages use more dynamic callbacks and such features, etc... I'm not sure what their answer to that is yet.